# Which built-in JAR file in Eclipse/RSA deals with creation of Junit Test Suite?

Tags: junit, eclipse-plugin, test-suite, rational-rsa

I am unable to find the built in JAR file in Eclipse/RSA that deals with creation of Junit Test Suite: File-> New -> Junit Test Suite

We are using RSA 8.0.2 version and with this RSA, currently the Test Suites are created in JUnit3 format by default. I have to modify this existing functionality (creating Junit3 TestSuite) to create Junit4 Test Suites with  annotations.

Please can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The New Junit Test Suite wizard page is `org.eclipse.jdt.junit.wizards.NewTestSuiteWizardPage` in the `org.eclipse.jdt.junit` plugin.

This is not going to be easy to modify. It would probably be easier the write a new plugin for a New wizard that you create.

Comment: Hi Greg, Thank you for the needful information.
 It would be great if you can give me the insight into this functionality interms of the required classes which are touched to have the implementation for junit 3 TestSuite.



Iam new to this RSA builtin plug-in creation and iam trying to understand it. It would be great if you can you help me out like, which plug-in deals with the creation of Junit Test Suite: File-> New -> Junit Test Suite. So that i can look into those and understand the flow of it.

Comment: You can find out which class is displaying a dialog using [Eclipse Plugin Spy](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy)